# High Level to ASM conversion

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-studio-2013, x86, inline-assembly

I'm learning assembly programming and I've been tasked with converting a for loop (along with any array use) into assembly within my program.

The program simply takes an encryption key (`EKey`) and uses it to encrypt an array of letters (`hello` for example).

**Here is the loop in C++**:

```
void encrypt_chars(int length, char EKey)
{
    char temp_char;                         // char temporary store

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)        // encrypt characters one at a time
    {
        temp_char = OChars[i];              // temp_char now contains the address values of the individual character
        __asm
        {
                push    eax                 // Save values contained within register to stack
                push    ecx

                movzx   ecx, temp_char
                push    ecx                 // Push argument #2
                lea     eax, EKey
                push    eax                 // Push argument #1
                call    encrypt
                add     esp, 8              // Clean parameters of stack
                mov     temp_char, al       // Move the temp character into a register    

                pop     ecx
                pop     eax
        }
        EChars[i] = temp_char;              // Store encrypted char in the encrypted chars array
    }
    return;

    // Inputs: register EAX = 32-bit address of Ekey,
    // ECX = the character to be encrypted (in the low 8-bit field, CL).
    // Output: register EAX = the encrypted value of the source character (in the low 8-bit field, AL).

    __asm
    {
    encrypt:
            push    ebp                 // Set stack
            mov     ebp, esp            // Set up the base pointer

            mov     eax, [ebp + 8]      // Move value of parameter 1 into EAX
            mov     ecx, [ebp + 12]     // Move value of parameter 2 into ECX
            push    edi                 // Used for string and memory array copying
            push    ecx                 // Loop counter for pushing character onto stack

            not     byte ptr[eax]       // Negation
            add     byte ptr[eax], 0x04 // Adds hex 4 to EKey
            movzx   edi, byte ptr[eax]  // Moves value of EKey into EDI using zeroes
            pop     eax                 // Pop the character value from stack
            xor     eax, edi            // XOR character to give encrypted value of source
            pop     edi                 // Pop original address of EDI from the stack

            rol     al, 1               // Rotates the encrypted value of source by 1 bit (left)
            rol     al, 1               // Rotates the encrypted value of source by 1 bit (left) again
            add     al, 0x04            // Adds hex 4 to encrypted value of source

            mov     esp, ebp            // Deallocate values
            pop     ebp                 // Restore the base pointer
            ret
    }

    //--- End of Assembly code
}
```

I've looked at the disassembly code and used that to rewrite the ASM code. I typed in the disassembly code as follows however it gives the following errors: http://gyazo.com/3b6875c9e1207df61df4e95506af7ed6

**Here is my code**:

```
void encrypt_chars(int length, char EKey)
{
    char temp_char;

    __asm
    {
        mov     DWORD PTR[rbp - 4], 0
        jmp     L2

    L3:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR[rbp - 4]
        cdqe
        cltq   

// ERROR HERE ^ above: error C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'opcode'; found 'newline'  
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR EChars[rax] 

// ERROR HERE ^ above: error C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'opcode'; found 'newline'  
// another error ^ above: error C2424: '[' : improper expression in 'second operand'

        mov     BYTE PTR[rbp - 5], al

        // OG code
        push    eax                 // Save values contained within register to stack
        push    ecx

        movzx   ecx, temp_char
        push    ecx                 // Push argument #2
        lea     eax, EKey
        push    eax                 // Push argument #1
        call    encrypt4
        add     esp, 8              // Clean parameters of stack
        mov     temp_char, al       // Move the temp character into a register    

        pop     ecx
        pop     eax

        // end of OG code

        mov     eax, DWORD PTR[rbp - 4]
        cdqe
        movzx   edx, BYTE PTR[rbp - 5] // ERROR HERE: error C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'opcode'; found 'newline'   
        mov     BYTE PTR DChars[rax], dl // ERROR HERE: error C2424: '[' : improper expression in 'first operand'

    L2:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR[rbp - 4]
        cmp     eax, DWORD PTR[rbp - 20]
        jl      L3

    }
    return;

    __asm
    {
    encrypt4:
            push    ebp                 // Set stack
            mov     ebp, esp            // Set up the base pointer

            mov     eax, [ebp + 8]      // Move value of parameter 1 into EAX
            mov     ecx, [ebp + 12]     // Move value of parameter 2 into ECX
            push    edi                 // Used for string and memory array copying
            push    ecx                 // Loop counter for pushing character onto stack

            not     byte ptr[eax]       // Negation
            add     byte ptr[eax], 0x04 // Adds hex 4 to EKey
            movzx   edi, byte ptr[eax]  // Moves value of EKey into EDI using zeroes
            pop     eax                 // Pop the character value from stack
            xor     eax, edi            // XOR character to give encrypted value of source
            pop     edi                 // Pop original address of EDI from the stack

            rol     al, 1               // Rotates the encrypted value of source by 1 bit (left)
            rol     al, 1               // Rotates the encrypted value of source by 1 bit (left) again
            add     al, 0x04            // Adds hex 4 to encrypted value of source

            mov     esp, ebp            // Deallocate values
            pop     ebp                 // Restore the base pointer
            ret
    }

    //--- End of Assembly code
}
```

Would anyone be able to point out where I'm going wrong please? I'm finding this relatively difficult so step-by-step explanations are most welcome. Please let me know where I'm going wrong. Thanks x

EDIT:

My full code: http://pastebin.com/tP9Dgvpn

Comment: Please edit your post and include the error messages there instead of linking to them. Make sure to post the text of the messages and not an image.

Comment: Especially since the link doesn't work from here for some reason. Anyway, what I can see is that you should definitely use labels and not stuff like `jge  encrypt_chars + 6Ah`.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Hi, I did not know. Apologies. Please see edit for the errors.

Comment: @Jester Would you be able to provide me with an example please?

Comment: Would also help to know which lines the errors apply to. I could also spot a broken line `mov     cl, byte ptr` which is clearly missing the operand. As for the jumps, just place a label (a name followed by a colon) on the line you want to jump to, and reference that by name.

Comment: @Jester I've made some improvements to my code, please would you see the edit? Thank you very much!

Comment: You are apparently trying to mix in 64 bit code ... that won't work.

Comment: @Jester What is the 32bit equivalent? :(

Comment: Delete the `cdqe` and the `cltq`, use `eax` and `ebp` instead of `rax` and `rbp`, respectively.

Comment: @jester Thank you very much! That's removed all of the errors however I am not getting the desired output. This is what I should get: http://gyazo.com/dccff6052526eb6b396658c98d7ff488 and here's what I'm getting: http://gyazo.com/3031a801f364edb179584d796cb23b27 Why is this happening, can you please explain? (Also see edit for full code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
void encrypt_chars(int length, char EKey, char *Msg)
{
    int InLength = length;
    int counter;

    __asm
    {
        push eax        // Counter
        mov eax, 0      // Zero counter
        push ebx        // Value
        mov ebx, InLength
        jmp     L2

L3:
        mov counter, EAX
        call    encrypt4
        inc eax         // Increment counter.

    L2:
        cmp     eax, ebx
        jl      L3      // Jump if we haven't reached our count.
        pop ebx
        pop eax
    }
    return;

    __asm
    {
    encrypt4:
            push    eax
            push    ebx
            push    edi

            mov     ebx, counter
            add     ebx, Msg
            mov     al, [ebx]      // Move character into al
            CBW                         // Make word.
            CWDE                        // Make Dword.


            not     byte ptr[EKey]       // Negation
            add     byte ptr[EKey], 0x04 // Adds hex 4 to EKey
            movzx   edi, byte ptr[EKey]  // Moves value of EKey into EDI using zeroes

            xor     eax, edi            // XOR character to give encrypted value of source
            pop     edi                 // Pop original address of EDI from the stack

            rol     al, 1               // Rotates the encrypted value of source by 1 bit (left)
            rol     al, 1               // Rotates the encrypted value of source by 1 bit (left) again
            add     al, 0x04            // Adds hex 4 to encrypted value of source

            mov [ebx], al
            pop     ebx
            pop     eax
            ret
    }

    //--- End of Assembly code
}
```

I call it with this snippet:

```
EKey = 'i';

sprintf(OChars, "hello");

printf("%s\n", OChars);
encrypt_chars(sizeof(OChars), EKey, OChars);
printf("%s\n", OChars);
```

My output looks like this:
hello

╧4▀↑█⌐

This matches your output but all except the first character.  I am convinced the algorithm looks correct and I can't spend any more time on it.  I believe it can be differences in character sets.  Try it out.

Good luck!

Comment: I went back and verified the hex.  This is correct to your picture.