# How to convert for loop in c++ to assembler?

Tags: c++, assembly

I am trying to convert the procedure encrypt_chars to assembler. I already have some x86 in assembly in the for loop, however I am trying to convert the remainder of the procedure into assembler. I'd be appreciative if you could help me

```
    void encrypt_chars (int length, char EKey)
{   char temp_char;                     // char temporary store

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)    // encrypt characters one at a time
    {
        temp_char = OChars [i];         //
        __asm {                         //
            push   eax                  // save register values on stack to be safe
            push   ecx                  //
                                        //
            movzx  ecx,temp_char        // set up registers (Nb this isn't StdCall or Cdecl)
            lea    eax,EKey             //
            call   encrypt12                // encrypt the character
            mov    temp_char,al         //
                                        //
            pop    ecx                  // restore original register values from stack
            pop    eax                  //
        }
        EChars [i] = temp_char;         // Store encrypted char in the encrypted chars array
    }
```

Comment: The best way to convert C++ to assembler is to use a C++ compiler.

Comment: well, I'm using visual studio currently. Any recommendations on how to do so?

Comment: @MikeVine I am asking a different question. I am asking how to convert the for loop into assembler.

Comment: My bad - I was thinking of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921422/high-level-to-asm-conversion), as I knew I saw this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next is the code for the "for" statement converted into assembler, register EDI is used as the control variable "i", if EDI is been changed by "encrypt21", just push it before and pop it after "call encrypt21" to preserve-restore its value. I changed the parameter "length" by "len" because the name gave me problems :

```
void encrypt_chars(int len, char EKey)
{   char temp_char;

__asm {   mov  edi, 0           ;FOR ( EDI = 0;

        fori:

        ;GET CURRENT CHAR.

          mov  al, OChars[edi]
          mov  temp_char, al

        ;ENCRYPT CURRENT CHAR.

          push   eax              // save register values on stack to be safe
          push   ecx
          movzx  ecx,temp_char  // set up registers (Nb this isn't StdCall or Cdecl)
          lea    eax,EKey
          call   encrypt12              // encrypt the character
          mov    temp_char,al
          pop    ecx        // restore original register values from stack
          pop    eax 

       ;STORE ENCRYPTED CHAR.

          mov  al, temp_char
          mov  EChars[ edi ], al

       ;FOR STATEMENT : FOR ( EDI = 0; EDI < LEN, EDI++ )

          inc  edi              ;EDI++.
          cmp  edi, len
          jb   fori             ;IF ( EDI < LEN ) JUMP.
      }
return;
}
```

Comment: If I was rated 15 I'd vote you up! Thank you very much. I just wandered in this case why would the variable i be controlled by EDI?

Comment: it's possible to use "i" but EDI is more "assembler".