# Understanding this disassembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I have a simple declaration in C++:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)        
    {
        temp_char = OChars[i];

    ...
    ...
```

`OChars[]` contains a string of text, maximum of 6 letters

The disassembly shown for `temp_char = OChars[i];` is:

```
mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-8]       //move i into EDX
mov         al,byte ptr [edx+0B44448h]      //move OChars[i] in to AL (lower 8bit of EAX)
mov         byte ptr [temp_char],al
```

I understand that  `mov   al,byte ptr [edx+0B44448h]` is moving the character stored in `OChars[i]` in to AL.

I don't understand `[edx+0B44448h]`.  I've checked the register `0x00B44448h` and it appears empty (although the characters stored in `OChars[]` seems to begin in `0x00B44440`).

I'm trying to convert the original C++ to inline ASM but don't know how to find out what I need to replace `[edx+0B44448h]` with on that particular line.

Really appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: `OChars` should begin at that address exactly. As such, you can just do `mov al, byte ptr [edx+OChars]`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29952656/how-to-convert-for-loop-in-c-to-assembler/29953506#29953506

Comment: If `0x00B44448h` is empty it's because there's nothing in `OChars[0]`.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, that's what I thought but looking at the registers whilst stepping through my program shows that they aren't. Here's a pic of my registers (the string I entered was 'scran'): http://i.gyazo.com/23d376fac551c8451cc822c561867cf7.png

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that, just means the first few entries of `OChars` are `0`. For example, you are unlikely to encounter character `0` because that signals end of string ;) Note that there is no such thing as "empty" memory - it is not empty, it just has value `0` and that may very well make sense.

Comment: The memory that is copied in the register AL is that at the memory address [EDX + 0B44448h], not that at the memory address 0B44448h.